# Value at Risk (VAR), TVAR, ES for uniform distribution

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

The following is a problem for Kaas et al. (2008) "Modern Actuarial Risk Theory".
I am trying to understand my concepts for TVaR, VaR, and CTE

Question: Give expressions from VaR, TVaR, and CTE in case S ~ Uniform[a,b]

My solution so far:
At confidence level $c$
VaR $=(b-a)c+a$
TVaR $=((b+\text{VaR}/2)+ $VaR
CTE $=(a-b/2)$

Am I correct? The book's solution is kind of different.

Comment: Welcome to the math.SE community :-)

Comment: IMHO, it would be helpful to explain the concepts, at least spelling out the abbreviations.

Comment: VAR-Value at risk
TVAR-Tail value at risk
CTE-Conditional tail expectation

TY- Thank you :P

Comment: Please integrate this stuff into your post by editing it (see bottom line 'share cite **edit** flag'). I'd guess this renders your questions more addressing.